# xmlrpc.py Connection refused error while using supervisor in docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, supervisord

hello guys im writing a docker file and compose with ubuntu 20.04 and try to install supervisor inside it
docker file :

```
...
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /src/app

ENV BACKENDENVIRONMENT 0

COPY gsigner .
COPY docker_requirements.txt ./

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


RUN apt-get update
RUN  apt install -y python-is-python3 
RUN  apt-get install -y python3.9
RUN  apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN  apt-get install gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl libssl- 
dev cargo -y
RUN  apt install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-all gcc 
python3-dev musl-dev
RUN  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
&&pip install -r docker_requirements.txt
RUN  mkdir /run/gsigner
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor


COPY backend_supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

## dockerfile updated

docker compose :

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  gsigner:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && supervisorctl reread && supervisorctl reload&&supervisorctl start daphne"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - static:/var/static/gsigner/
      - media:/var/media/gsigner/
      - gsigner:/src/app/
      - log:/var/log/gsigner/







volumes:
  static:
  media:
  log:
  gsigner:
```

## dockercompose updated

- daphne is my program name in my supervisor conf file

my supervisor conf file :

```
    [supervisord]
    [supervisorctl]
    [program:daphne]
    command=daphne gsigner.asgi:application
    directory=/src/app/gsigner/
    user=root
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
```

i really did not realize what is happening here

and this is the err msg :
error:error: <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Do you have the same problem without supervisord?  If not, can you restructure your application to have multiple containers, with just one process in each?  (What other things is supervisord running and is there a specific reason they must be in the same container?)

Comment: acctully its just one containet and just one supervisor config file which i added into it

Comment: In most uses you shouldn't use supervisord.  There's not enough information in this question in its current form to say why you're getting this error, but if you don't have it without supervisord, then I'd just skip installing it.

Comment: i did update my files can you check again  ? i really need to use supervisor